# How to launch Orca and use it?

Tags: xfce, orca

I find it really hard to know how to make Orca work properly in Xubuntu.
How can an accessibility tool be so hard to use ?

So, can anyone help me to find what I need to use Screen reader and to configure it ?

Answer (score 0):

Enable the 'Enabled Assistive Technologies' checkbox in the Accessibility settings in Settings Manager, then add the default Orca shortcut of Super + Alt + S in the Applications Shortcuts tab of the Keyboard settings.

https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/accessibility

https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/-/issues/169

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the accessibility support in your distribution's settings (normally some lone checkbox somewhere). After that, all that is required is starting `orca`, for example via command line, and then you should hear a voice reading out anything you click on or focus. You can configure orca via `orca -s`.